# Autopost to facebook from android

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing an android app that requires to automatically post on user's facebook wall when a button is clicked. The share button doesn't require any user interaction and a pre-defined text will be posted on the wall using only button click.

Is there anyway this can be done? Any links for such feature?

NB: The condition is to have facebook app already installed in the device and the user must log in in facebook app (to make things easier and avoid authentication procedures).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is one simple method to do this :

```
private void publishStory(String title, String youneed2, String youneed3) {

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null){
        // Check for publish permissions    
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                    .NewPermissionsRequest(getActivity(), PERMISSIONS);
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
            return;
        }
        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("name", title);
        postParams.putString("caption", "bla bla");
        postParams.putString("description", "bla bla");
        postParams.putString("link", "http://www.yoursite.com");
        postParams.putString("picture", "http://linktoyourimage.com");

        Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                JSONObject graphResponse = response
                        .getGraphObject()
                        .getInnerJSONObject();
                String postId = null;
                try {
                    postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG,
                            "JSON error "+ e.getMessage());
                }
                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                if (error != null) {
                    debug.print("erreur");
                } 
            }
        };
        Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, 
        HttpMethod.POST, callback);
        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();
    }
}
```

Don't forget that you need a valid Token, then call `PublishStory()` and build your post with the Bundle.

Hope this help

**Edit**

Add these line before your onCreate()

```
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
private static final String PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY = "pendingPublishReauthorization";
private boolean pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tried this and it gives me some errors.
The main error cause seems to be this line:
'Session session = Session.getActiveSession();'
I have imported all that has to be imported.

It says:
the method getActiveSession() is undefined for the type SpellCheckerService.Session

Any further help?

Comment: I can't run the project as it has errors in the workspace. And the error begin when the Session object is created.

Comment: Ok now the session error is gone, but still there are few more errors.
if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) in this line I get the error in the workspace too. it says: PERMISSIONS cannot be resolved to a variable.